# How to make li one lined with others

Tags: html, css

I want my text in every li has the same gap after span like so:

```
Street     Am Stadtpark 3
Zip        Code 1030
City       Vienna
```

I had my strong as absolute and left, but then main ul won't adjust its width with strong content(content goes out of borders).

```html
<html>
<head>
<title>Page Title</title>
<style>
ul{
 max-width: 200px;
    background: wheat;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<ul>
    <li><span>Street</span> <strong>Am Stadtpark 3</strong></li>
    <li><span>Zip Code </span><strong>1030</strong></li>
    <li><span>City </span><strong>Vienna</strong></li>
</ul>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Use CSS grid, `<dt>`/`<dd>` or `<table>` elements for that purpose.

Answer (score 2):

I've used the same snippet of yours and modified some css.

```css
ul {
    padding:0;
}

ul li {
  list-style-type: none;
}

ul li span {
 display: inline-block;
 width: 100px;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li><span>Street</span><strong>Am Stadtpark 3</strong></li>
  <li><span>Zip Code </span><strong>1030</strong></li>
  <li><span>City </span><strong>Vienna</strong></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

## Solution 1: CSS grid

You can use CSS grid for this purpose: all you need is to let the grid decide how many rows it wants, but specifying that there should only be two autosized columns:

```css
.address {
  max-width: 200px;
  background: wheat;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(2, auto);

}

.value {
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<div class="address">
  <div class="field">Street</div>
  <div class="value">Am Standtpark 3</div>
  
  <div class="field">Zip Code</div>
  <div class="value">1030</div>
  
  <div class="field">City</div>
  <div class="value">Vienna</div>
</div>
```

## Solution 2: Use `<table>`

Not my most favourite approach, since you're technically not presenting tabulated data, but that again depends on what context you are displaying the information in:

```css
table {
  max-width: 200px;
  background: wheat;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Street</td>
      <td><strong>Am Standtpark 3</strong></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Zip Code</td>
      <td><strong>1030</strong></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>City</td>
      <td><strong>Vienna</strong></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
ul{
    max-width: 200px;
    background: wheat;
}

 .street, .zip, .city {
  display: inline-block;
}

.main {
  width: 90px;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li class="main street">Street</li>
  <li class="street">Am Stadtpark 3</li>
  <li class="main zip">Zip Code</li>
  <li class="zip">1030</li>
  <li class="main city">City</li>
  <li class="city">Vienna</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

CSS-Tables can do that.

```css
ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  max-width: 200px;
  background: wheat;
}

li {
  display: table-row;
}

li span,
li strong {
  display: table-cell;
  border: 1px solid grey;
}

li span{
  padding-right:4px;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li><span>Street</span> <strong>Am Stadtpark 3</strong></li>
  <li><span>Zip Code </span><strong>1030</strong></li>
  <li><span>City </span><strong>Vienna</strong></li>
</ul>
```